# How to use Swagger Codegen TypeScript Fetch Client

Tags: typescript, npm, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

Has anyone successfully used the Swagger Code Generator to create a TypeScript Fetch client that can be used within the browser?  I'm trying to use the generated API client within a React application that uses TypeScript.

Although I've successfully generated a client (i.e. the api.ts file), I'm getting hung up on the fact that it begins with the following imports:

```
import * as querystring from "querystring";
import * as url from "url";

import * as isomorphicFetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import * as assign from "core-js/library/fn/object/assign";

interface Dictionary<T> { [index: string]: T; }
export interface FetchAPI { (url: string, init?: any): Promise<any>; }

...
```

While I can successfully find the TypeScript typings (i.e. @types) for isomorphic-fetch and core-js, I can't find typings for querystring and url.  As a result, I'm getting `[ts] Cannot find module...` for the `querystring`, `url` and also the `assign` imports.

Is this client not actually intended to be used within the browser?  Otherwise, can anyone provide any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Here are some tests for Typescript-Fetch Petstore client: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-fetch/tests/default/test. Would these help?

Comment: Just FYI: You can also generate a TypeScript Fetch client from a swagger file with NSwag (http://nswag.org, I'm the author). It imports only the expected definitions, i.e. whatwg-fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the link, wing328, that ended up taking me down the path that lead to the 'TypeScript Fetch'-specific readme.  In particular, this section here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-fetch/builds/es6-target#installation explains that the Swagger Code Generator does not directly create JavaScript - you must run `npm install` or `npm publish'.  You'll then be able to find the JavaScript-based API and associated typings in the dist folder.